# How to update div element attribute value in ember js and tabulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, tabulator

I am using tabulator api in ember js framework to display dynamic tables. where on tab focus is not moving from 1st column to 3rd column because 2nd column is disabled. To do this I am trying to update the second column tabindex attribute as "-1"(by defaule all columns it is zero). so that tab focus skip from second comumn and move to third column. I have used jquery to do this but it didn't work out.

```
table = new Tabulator("#sample-table", {
            data:self.get('tableData'),
            selectable:true,
            columns:self.get('tableColumnData'),
            keybindings:true,            
            cellEdited:function(cell){                              
                var accnamecol = $("[tabulator-field=ACCNAME]").tabindex=-1;   
}
```

tabindex attribute need to modify in the below dom.

Now I am able to update the attribute value in the div tab with jquery.
The actual problem I am facing with tabulator is, I have 4 columns in the row.
After entering the value in first column, making ajax call and updating second column. Now after entering tab the cursor is moving back to the first column instead of third column.

The below code is only partial, unable to copy whole code, it's too big.

```
            table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
            data:self.get('tableData'),
            selectable:1,
            height:"auto",
            columns:self.get('tableColumnData'),
            keybindings:true,

            cellEdited:function(cell){                  
                self.cellBlur(cell, row,value, self.get("testData"));
            },
        });        

   },
   cellBlur: function(cell, row, value, testData){
        self.send('execute',value,id,row); 
        //table.scrollToColumn(cell.getField(), "middle", false);
        //console.log("cell nav right1 "+cell.getField())
        //if(cell.getField() === "NAME"){
        //cell.nav().right();
        //self.get('table').navigateNext();
        //}

    },
    actions: {
     self.get('services').fetch(self.get('services').getModuleUrl('TEST'), 'controller/test', requestdto, 'POST').then(function (json) {
                    if (json !== null && json.data !== null) {
        execute: function (value, eventId, fieldName) {                                                                                     

                            self.get('table').updateRow(self.get('rowid'),tempObj);                         
                        }   

        }
        }
        },
```

I am using self.get('table').updateRow(self.get('rowid'),tempObj); to update second column data. I think table is re-creating after data populated to the second column.

My requirement is, the cursor should move to third column.

Comment: Please put working code here so that we can see what you are trying to do

Comment: @dota2pro updated the query and descriptioon, your help is higly appreciated.

Comment: Please create working demo that shows Table like this https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/2b9jnLrx/

Comment: You could use tabulator's tableBuilt attribute callback to know when it re-creates to know for sure it does when you populate the second column with data. See http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/callbacks#table